# Programming printing after looping

Tags: c

I am trying to make hexagons tiles. I have the shape but I am doing something wrong while printing them.

Here is my code and what I tried:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

  int main() {

    int i, x;

    for (i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {

      for (x = 1; x <= 2; x++) {
        printf("  %d,%d\t  \n", i, x);
        printf(" / \t \\\n");
        printf("| \t  |\n");
        printf("| \t  |\n");
        printf(" \\ \t /\n");
      }

      printf("\n\n");

    }
  }
```

I need them horizontal and not vertical.

I know what I did wrong, which is printing the hex-shape "m,n+1" below the hex-shape "m,n", instead of on its right side.
But I don't know how to fix it. Thanks!

Fixed!

**Update:
Results now are**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define COLS 4
#define ROWS 3

void subrow(char* pcWhat, char* pcEndWhat)
{  int col;
   for (col = 0; col < COLS; col++) {
     printf("%s", pcWhat);
   }
   printf("%s\n", pcEndWhat);
}
void indexedSubrow(char* pcWhat, char* pcEndWhat, int row, int offset)
{  int col;
   for (col = 0; col < COLS; col++) {
         printf(pcWhat, row, col+offset);
       }

   printf("%s\n", pcEndWhat);
}

int main(void) {
    int i, x;


    subrow("  ___     ","");


    for (i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
           if(i==0){
               subrow(" /   \\    ","  ");
      indexedSubrow("/ %d,%d \\___"," ", i, 0);
             subrow("\\     /   ","\\");
      indexedSubrow(" \\___/ %d,%d"," \\", i, 1);  


      }

   //else if(i==ROWS-1){}


      else{
      subrow(" /   \\    "," /");
      indexedSubrow("/ %d,%d \\___","/", i, 0);
      subrow("\\     /   ","\\");
      indexedSubrow(" \\___/ %d,%d"," \\", i, 1);
           }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**More explanation and art of what I need:**

```
The last subrow is:
\     /   \     /   \     /   \     /   \
 \___/ 2,1 \___/ 2,3 \___/ 2,5 \___/ 2,7 \

Which should be
\     /   \     /   \     /   \     /   \
 \___/ 2,1 \___/ 2,3 \___/ 2,5 \___/ 2,7 \
     \     /   \     /   \     /   \     /
      \___/     \___/     \___/     \___/

So the missing part is:
     \     /   \     /   \     /   \     /
      \___/     \___/     \___/     \___/
```

Also I am curious how to add numbers ("Let's say 1 as a second digit in all of the hexagon grids") Example:

Current art:

```
  ___       ___       ___       ___     
 /   \     /   \     /   \     /   \      
/ 0,0 \___/ 0,1 \___/ 0,2 \___/ 0,3 \___ 
\     /   \     /   \     /   \     /   \
 \___/ 0,1 \___/ 0,2 \___/ 0,3 \___/ 0,4 \
 /   \     /   \     /   \     /   \     /
/ 1,0 \___/ 1,1 \___/ 1,2 \___/ 1,3 \___/
\     /   \     /   \     /   \     /   \
 \___/ 1,1 \___/ 1,2 \___/ 1,3 \___/ 1,4 \
 /   \     /   \     /   \     /   \     /
/ 2,0 \___/ 2,1 \___/ 2,2 \___/ 2,3 \___/
\     /   \     /   \     /   \     /   \
 \___/ 2,1 \___/ 2,2 \___/ 2,3 \___/ 2,4 \
```

**Expecting:** ( Overall as the final result )

```
  ___       ___       ___       ___     
 /   \     /   \     /   \     /   \      
/ 0,0 \___/ 0,2 \___/ 0,4 \___/ 0,6 \___ 
\  1  /   \  1  /   \  1  /   \  1  /   \
 \___/ 0,1 \___/ 0,3 \___/ 0,5 \___/ 0,7 \
 /   \  1  /   \  1  /   \  1  /   \  1  /
/ 1,0 \___/ 1,2 \___/ 1,4 \___/ 1,6 \___/
\  1  /   \  1  /   \  1  /   \  1  /   \
 \___/ 1,1 \___/ 1,3 \___/ 1,5 \___/ 1,7 \
 /   \  1  /   \  1  /   \  1  /   \  1  /
/ 2,0 \___/ 2,2 \___/ 2,4 \___/ 2,6 \___/
\  1  /   \  1  /   \  1  /   \  1  /   \
 \___/ 2,1 \___/ 2,3 \___/ 2,5 \___/ 2,7 \
     \  1  /   \  1  /   \  1  /   \  1  /
      \___/     \___/     \___/     \___/
```

Thanks!

Comment: You should check out https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54277/ascii-connected-hexagons - first time I've  considered  a question to be a dupe of/solved by a golf challenge

Comment: @sardar he wants 4 hexagons arranged in a 2x2 not a 1x4

Comment: Don't use tabs; use spaces.

Comment: Can't see anything different between "got" and "expected". Please post them as text, in the question, instead of console grab. If you can't do that programmtically (hence the question) do it with a text editor.

Comment: Something like this http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/hexagonal_part1/hex_array.jpg
checkout google for hexagon grid coordinates

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Alright thanks, I used spaces. Could you please help me doing this?

Comment: I can't tell from your free-hand diagram what you actually want as a shape. You should put the images into the question as 'code'. You should definitely show what you want as 'code' (that is, as text in the question, indented so it appears like code — for maximum panache, add a line before it containing `<!-- language: lang-none -->` with a blank line above and below it to suppress code highlighting in the image). If it comes down to tesselating an array of hexagons, it will be more interesting.  You'd probably need 'vertical' hexagons like you currently show and 'horizontal' hexagons to mesh.

Comment: Nice of you to keep your post updated but be careful not to remove the entire "Question" part (which is Stack Overflow's mantra: "Ask questions, get answers"). As it is, it is getting a bit hard to tell what exactly you are asking from the community, and what particular problem the answers below are referring to. If it gets any worse (the threshold varies per person), I'm inclined to close as "Unclear what you are asking".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to make rows of two (probably more) hex shapes each.
For that you must not print newlines after a sub-row of one hex shape.
Instead print the sub-rows of all (two) hex shapes, wiht appropriate whitespace to align them. For that, going away from tabs is probably helpful.
So basically you should change from

```
  for (x = 1; x <= 2; x++) {
    printf("  %d,%d\t  \n", i, x);
    printf(" / \t \\\n");
    printf("| \t  |\n");
    printf("| \t  |\n");
    printf(" \\ \t /\n");
  }
```

to

```
    for (i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {

      for (x = 1; x <= 2; x++) {
        printf("  %d,%d  ", i, x);
      }
      printf("\n");
      for (x = 1; x <= 2; x++) {
        printf(" /   \\ ");
      }
      printf("\n");
      for (x = 1; x <= 2; x++) {
        printf("|     |");
      }
      printf("\n");
      for (x = 1; x <= 2; x++) {
        printf("|     |");
      }
      printf("\n");
      for (x = 1; x <= 2; x++) {
        printf(" \\   / ");
      }
      printf("\n");
    }
```

Note 1, I did not fine-tune the whitespace between the hex shapes in one row. You will have to do that yourself. So the output below might not satisfy you directly, but it should be visible that the core problem is solved.

Note 2, even this way you will get a square grid of hex-shapes.
If you actually want a hex-grid of hex-shapes, you have to change the position of the `|` in every second hex row.

Output:

```
  1,1    1,2
 /   \  /   \
|     ||     |
|     ||     |
 \   /  \   /
  2,1    2,2
 /   \  /   \
|     ||     |
|     ||     |
 \   /  \   /
```

I played around, attempting to make something of a hex grid, according to Note2.
I also provide an attempt at ascii art of your pixel picture,
in the second hex-grid version,
based on Jonathan Lefflers proposal to turn the hexes by 90 degrees.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define COLS 4
#define ROWS 3

void subrow(char* pcWhat, char* pcEndWhat)
{  int col;
   for (col = 0; col < COLS; col++) {
     printf("%s", pcWhat);
   }
   printf("%s\n", pcEndWhat);
}
void indexedSubrow(char* pcWhat, char* pcEndWhat, int row, int offset)
{  int col;
   for (col = 0; col < COLS; col++) {
     printf(pcWhat, row, col*2+offset);
   }
   printf("%s\n", pcEndWhat);
}

int main(void) {
    int i, x;

    for (i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {

      for (x = 1; x <= 2; x++) {
        printf("  %d,%d  ", i, x);
      }
      printf("\n");
      for (x = 1; x <= 2; x++) {
        printf(" /   \\ ");
      }
      printf("\n");
      for (x = 1; x <= 2; x++) {
        printf("|     |");
      }
      printf("\n");
      for (x = 1; x <= 2; x++) {
        printf("|     |");
      }
      printf("\n");
      for (x = 1; x <= 2; x++) {
        printf(" \\   / ");
      }
      printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("\n");

    for (i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
      subrow("   / \\  ","");
      subrow("  /   \\ ","");
      subrow(" /     \\","");
      subrow("|       ","|");
      subrow("|       ","|");
      subrow(" \\     /","");
      subrow("  \\   / ","");
      subrow("   \\ /  ","");
      subrow("    |   ","");
      subrow("    |   ","");
     }
      subrow("   / \\  ","");
      subrow("  /   \\ ","");
      subrow(" /     \\","");
      subrow("|       ","|");
      subrow("|       ","|");
      subrow(" \\     /","");
      subrow("  \\   / ","");
      subrow("   \\ /  ","");
      printf("\n");
      printf("\n");

    subrow("  ___     ","");
    for (i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
             subrow(" /   \\    "," /");
      indexedSubrow("/ %d,%d \\___","/", i, 0);
             subrow("\\     /   ","\\");
      indexedSubrow(" \\___/ %d,%d"," \\", i, 1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output vertical hexes:

```
   / \     / \     / \     / \
  /   \   /   \   /   \   /   \
 /     \ /     \ /     \ /     \
|       |       |       |       |
|       |       |       |       |
 \     / \     / \     / \     /
  \   /   \   /   \   /   \   /
   \ /     \ /     \ /     \ /
    |       |       |       |
    |       |       |       |
   / \     / \     / \     / \
  /   \   /   \   /   \   /   \
 /     \ /     \ /     \ /     \
|       |       |       |       |
|       |       |       |       |
 \     / \     / \     / \     /
  \   /   \   /   \   /   \   /
   \ /     \ /     \ /     \ /
```

Output horizontal hexes:

```
  ___       ___       ___       ___
 /   \     /   \     /   \     /   \     /
/ 0,0 \___/ 0,2 \___/ 0,4 \___/ 0,6 \___/
\     /   \     /   \     /   \     /   \
 \___/ 0,1 \___/ 0,3 \___/ 0,5 \___/ 0,7 \
 /   \     /   \     /   \     /   \     /
/ 1,0 \___/ 1,2 \___/ 1,4 \___/ 1,6 \___/
\     /   \     /   \     /   \     /   \
 \___/ 1,1 \___/ 1,3 \___/ 1,5 \___/ 1,7 \
 /   \     /   \     /   \     /   \     /
/ 2,0 \___/ 2,2 \___/ 2,4 \___/ 2,6 \___/
\     /   \     /   \     /   \     /   \
 \___/ 2,1 \___/ 2,3 \___/ 2,5 \___/ 2,7 \
```

I am sure that you will not like the parts on the edges and the position of the digits,
but that is for yourself to tune to your taste.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this earlier the same as you but the shape got mixed. I mean not looking so proper or accurate.

Comment: Does that mean I misunderstood your goal? What do you want different?

Comment: Yeah, it is the same but I am trying to have them look more accurate. Thanks!

Comment: If you add an ascii-art of the desired output in the question, preferably as in formatting as "code" (use the "{}" button), I might be able to get closer. But the fine-tuning of the output prettiness should not be considered part of this question.

Comment: Thanks. Also can you help me doing this http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/hexagonal_part1/hex_array.jpg ? Please please I have been trying with no luck! This is all I need seriously. I will be very happy.

Comment: You did not give an ascii art version of the desired output. Please note that the compromises needed to turn a pixel picture into ascii art are very much opinion depending. It is almost sure that you won't like the compromises someone else makes. It will really be better to do it yourself.

Comment: Thankssss! I appreciate. This is exactly what I wanted and I "LIKE IT". I fixed the shape by running if statement to check if i == 0 and another one for i==row-1 and now I have the full working one ;)

Comment: Well, the top part works fine but not the bottom. Do you have any idea what I should do? Look at my question. It is updated!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161467/discussion-between-yunnosch-and-hobaa).

Comment: If you want more help, please, please show an ascii art of what result you want. "top part works fine but not the bottom" is simply not enough for me to guees what exactly you want differently. I can only see that you seem to have problems with the index digits.

Comment: Okay, I updated my question with some more explanation and the ascii art. Please scroll check it.

Comment: In order to get the desired result you need to fine-tune the edge cases. If necessary print the first 2-3 subrows separatly, outside of the "row" loop. Same for the last 2-3 subrows and for the end of each subrow, as supported by the second string parameter. The additional "1"s you seem to want can simply be harcoded into the string given as parameter to the function `subrow()`. I am sure you will manage.

Comment: From your question "So the missing part is:", it shows exactly the two special subrows() at the end, i.e. one of the edge cases. You can print them  after the row-loop with two calls to subrow(). If necessary add another parameter to subrow() giving the row-specific number of columns, instead of using a global configuration like I did.

Comment: I tried so many times but I couldn't get it to work ;( Please please help me with this final thing and that's it. I don't need anything else after.

Comment: Can you see the difference between the regular part and the edges? The regular part is most of the output, it is generated inside the nested loops. The regular part works inside the filed, but at the edges it looks wrong. You need to polish the edges by printing special case handling before the regular part, after the regular part and inside the regular part at the end of each subrow. The latter I supported with the second string parameter. Before and after can just be printed to taste. If the row ends with what looks like half a hex, fix it by special case-printing the other half to taste.

Comment: You have to learn regular-case-and-special-case thinking. There is no way around it. Go on playing with the code I have provided, with its parameters, with the loop constructs. Change something, see the output, decide whether it gets you closer to your goal. If not, change back, but keep in mind the effect it had, it might be the tool for a future desire. Learn by toying. That is my favorite method for learning myself and for teaching. I have the feeling that if I help you with this "final" thing I might actually hurt your progress. Please understand.

Comment: Two comments ago I had a confusing typo, "filed" should be "field".

Comment: Actually, I am not trying to learn programming for now. It is a task that I have to do. And I understand you. It is a good way, but I gave up. Been trying for 4-5 hours I swear and everytime something fits, other thing crashes. I just want to have this done because I can't and I couldn't handle it anymore. I should learn from this to do harder ones.  
I think for you it is like 1+1 for me it is like infinite numbers. Let's say (97835*7467/87656)^78345. It takes time to reach that level, and the task's deadline is about to be over.

Comment: Did you spot the obvious way to add the missing edge case?

Comment: I managed to fix it. As you said, "Puzzle". It now works well. But so many things need to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    int i, x;

    for (i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {

  for (x = 1; x <= 2; x++) {
    printf("    %d,%d    ", i, x);
  }
  printf("\n");
  for (x = 1; x <= 2; x++) {
    printf(" /      \\  ");
  }
  printf("\n");
  for (x = 1; x <= 2; x++) {
    printf("|        | ");
  }
  printf("\n");
  for (x = 1; x <= 2; x++) {
    printf("|        | ");
  }
  printf("\n");
  for (x = 1; x <= 2; x++) {
    printf(" \\      /  ");
  }
  printf("\n");

    }
}
```

The results would be:

```
    1,1        1,2    
 /      \   /      \  
|        | |        | 
|        | |        | 
 \      /   \      /  
    2,1        2,2    
 /      \   /      \  
|        | |        | 
|        | |        | 
 \      /   \      /
```

Simple programme I just created with this thing using C:

```
   0,0      0,1      0,2
 /     \  /     \  /     \
|   3   ||       ||   1   |
 \     /  \     /  \     /
      1,0      1,1      1,2
    /     \  /     \  /     \
   |   1   ||   a   ||   2   |
    \     /  \     /  \     /
   2,0      2,1      2,2
 /     \  /     \  /     \
|   2   ||   1   ||       |
 \     /  \     /  \     /
```

Comment: I do like your effort, but generally answers explain how and why you do things differently from the original post in order to help them correct their code. "*Maybe try this:*" doesn't quite count as explanation. Also, don't `printf("\n");` a single character, that is what `putchar('\n');` is for. (though a good compiler should optimize for you, you don't want to give sloppy examples). All in all, interesting code, just needs good explanation.

Comment: Ahh alright, thanks for the advice. Anyways, I just pasted the code because "Yunnosch" explained it and I was just trying to put the code with the new accurate shape. Thought it would be spam. Thanks again! Btw the formatter that I usually use, https://www.tutorialspoint.com/online_c_formatter.htm doesn't work for a reason.

Comment: No problem, I'm just trying to help you be a bit more successful here. One of the most frequent comments on predominantly code-only answers is to just please add a bit more explanation. Most of the point being that you only have control over your answer. Any other answer that might have similar rational may be changed or deleted altogether. By insuring you have adequate explanation in your answer, you insure all needed explanation remains with the question regardless what occurs with other answers.